# Exec format error. Binary file not executable

Tags: linux, shell

I'm under

```
Linux version 3.3.4-5.fc17.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-14.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.7.0 20120504 (Red Hat 4.7.0-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon May 7 17:29:34 UTC 2012
```

trying to run a basic executable script.ksh file with permission 775 and containing:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "hello ya"
```

but I have:

```
$./script.ksh
 ./script.ksh: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

the problem looks like to come from the shebang but I can't figure out why and how. 
I can run the script by doing this (note the weird output for the first line):

```
$ ksh script.ksh
script.ksh[1]: ?o?;??#!/bin/ksh: not found [No such file or directory]
hello ya
```

some (maybe) useful output:

```
$ file script.ksh
script.ksh: Korn shell script, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text executable
$ which ksh
/bin/ksh
```

do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem come from the option

```
set bomb
```

in the .vimrc config file of vim. Comment this line solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first line begins with some invisible characters, as shown in your error message:

> `?o?;??#!/bin/ksh`: not found

You can confirm this with

```
od -t x1c -N 10 script.ksh
```

Remove those characters, and it will now begin with the magic `#!`.  One way you might be able to do that is

```
sed -i -e '1s/^[^#]*//' script.ksh
```

Test it first without the `-i` option (you can pipe it into `od` to check the result).

Comment: indeed, that's what the option "bomb" does in vim: prepending a BOM mark to the file.

Comment: I thought so - but reasoned that the explanation might be more valuable than the fix, in case there are other editors that are broken in the same way.